# FBWC and Zero Memory (ZM) RAID Controller on HP DL360p

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I got a chance to work on HP DL360p Gen8 server with Smart Array controller P420i/ZM

1. What are the advantage of having FBWC or BBWC
2. Will it be possible to add an external P420/1GB or P420/2GB to this server.
3. Can a FBWC give better performance for RAID rebuild for replacement hard disk (we use RAID 1)
4. Overall performance could get affected by Zero Memory controller ?

Can someone please share your insight on this.

Answer (score 2):

FBWC is the only option for modern HP controllers. BBWC is not offered anymore.

There is very little practical use for the Zero-memory controller unless local disk performance isn't important to you.

Otherwise, you will always want to have a cache available... this is necessary for some of the RAID controller options and being able to use SSDs.

Comment: The only reason I can see to use the zero-mem-option would be for booting very static OS's such as ESXi. Otherwise spot-on.

Comment: Thank you very much it seems with ZM we can only go with RAID 1, 0 and 1+0. Will it be possible to add an external controller like P420 with 1GB FBWC on a server already having controller with ZM

Comment: All you need is to add the cache and flash capacitor unit. You don't need a new controller.